# Removal of special symbols from the textBox

Tags: vb.net, textbox, serial-port, symbols

I am working with an application which receives data from a weighing scale with an RS232 port.

The problem is that the data received from the scale, which is received in a textbox, looks like this:

`↑ N : 25,5 Kg`

I tried to eliminate and delete the up arrow and all other symbols and letters but my code didn't work.

I just need the number without anything else.

```
Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        Try
          Dim textrceveid As String
          textrceveid = SerialPort1.ReadExisting().ToString().Replace("N:", "").Replace("kg", "")
          ReceivedText(textrceveid) 'Automatically called whenever data is received on the Serial port

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
End Sub

Private Sub rtbReceived_TabIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rtbReceived.TabIndexChanged
    Dim numText As Regex = New Regex("[^\d]")
    rtbReceived.Text = numText.Replace(rtbReceived.Text, "")
End Sub

Private Sub rtbReceived_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles rtbReceived.KeyPress

    If (Not Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) AndAlso Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)) Then
      e.Handled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

[picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZypVy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There is many approaches, the followed is to be considered as an alternative only in your scenario.

```
    Dim testString As String = "↑N: 25,5 Kg"

    Dim patternWithDecimal As String = "([0-9]+)([.,])([0-9]+)"

    For Each m As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match In System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(testString, patternWithDecimal)
        Console.WriteLine(m.Value)
    Next
```

Or

```
    Dim theFirstNumericPart As String = testString.Split(CChar(" ")).FirstOrDefault(Function(part) IsNumeric(part))
    Console.WriteLine(theFirstNumericPart)
```

Or

```
    Dim mDbl as Double
    If Double.TryParse(New String((From sChr In testString Where "1234567890.,-+".IndexOf(sChr) > -1).ToArray), mDbl) Then
        Console.WriteLine(mDbl.ToString)
    End If
```

Or (Credit to @AndrewMorton)

```
Dim numberString = Regex.Replace(testString, "[^0-9,.]", "")
```

Comment: Another one for you: `Dim numberString = Regex.Replace(testString, "[^0-9,.]", "")`.

Comment: (You can write `CChar(" ")` as `" "c`.)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers
i found the answer after a Deep Debugging :
the up arrow ↑ is a **vbFormFeed**

i just writed that

```
textrceveid = textrceveid.Replace(vbFormFeed, "").Replace("N:", "").Replace("kg", "").Trim
```

Before : `↑ N : 25,5 Kg`

After :  `25,5`